# Crear un nuevo archivo excel si no existe en la carpeta c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Tengo una plantilla de excel, desde mi aplicacion la modifico y la guardo en una carpeta, lo que quiero hacer es que al volverla abrir la plantilla y modificarla se guarde en la carpeta pero con otro nombre.

Con esto abro la plantilla

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            Excel._Workbook libro;
            Excel._Worksheet hoja;
            libro = app.Workbooks.Open(@"ruta", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Y con esto lo guardo en la carpeta

```
libro.SaveAs(@"ruta+nombre, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Comment: no entiendo cual es el problema, si defines una ruta y nombre validos con el SaveAs() deberias poder guardar el excel, pero tienes que generar ese otro nombre

Comment: Que al querer guardar otro documento con esa plantilla, me pida que lo sobreescriba por eso necesita otro nombre

Comment: ok pero entonces ese nombre lo quieres definir dinamicamente ?

Comment: Podría ser con un conteo de 1 en 1

Answer (score 2):

Puedes preguntar primero si el archivo existe.

```
if(File.Exists(ruta+nombre)){
  libro.SaveAs(@"ruta+nombre+"(1)", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
} else {
  libro.SaveAs(@"ruta+nombre, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrias generar un nombre que tenga la fecha, como ser

```
string ruta = ....;

string nombre = string.Format("Prefijo_{0:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.xls", DateTime.Now);

string fullPath = Path.Combine(ruta, nombre);

libro.SaveAs(fullPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ....
```

de esta forma cuando realices el save del excel tendras uno nuevo basado en la fecha de ese momento

En `Prefijo` puede definir algo fijo o ver de tomar con el

[Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=netframework-4.7.2)

el nombre del archivo original